# Custom Tomcat logging class needs ServletContext

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, java.util.logging

I have to use a custom logger for Tomcat. Extending `java.util.logging.Handler` I implemented a bridge to the custom logger. It gets instanciated via `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`.

But it needs to beconfigured by a property file from the war. So I need the ServletContext to do `servletContext.getResourceAsStream(iniFileName)`. Since the custom Logger is created by the java logging mechanism, I am not able to get the ServletContext from a Servlet constructor or via dependency injection.

How do I get a ServletContext before any Servlet was created?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. But as a fast workaround you can consider using a singleton.

Comment: You can't because the `ServletContext` will be available only per request. You can instead have a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and in the `contextInitialized` method load the property attribute in a `static String` (or something else) and use it later wherever you want/need. Or even better, make usage of a cache to load the properties there and then use the properties elsewhere in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ServletContextListener and instantiate your handler programmatically. If you must instantiate it via loggin.property , you can still look for your handler instances via the logger API and configure it then.

Comment: I implemented a `ServletContextListener` and added `<listener><listener-class>com.mycompany.MyServletListener</listener-class></listener>` to the web.xml deployment descriptor. Now I get the ServletContext before anything important has to be logged.